# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'listeners' of undefined - ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am having this error message on the browser after building my ionic 3 app:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'listeners' of undefined.TypeError: Cannot read property 'listeners' of undefined
        at module.exports.<anonymous> (main.js:520)
        at module.exports.emit (events.js:146)
        at module.exports.ClientRequest._connect (request.js:268)
        at request.js:159
        at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
        at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4626)
        at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
        at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
        at polyfills.js:3
        at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4617)
        at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at o (polyfills.js:3)
        at c (polyfills.js:3)
        at polyfills.js:3
        at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4617)
        at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at o (polyfills.js:3)
```

**Ionic info**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.3, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.7.0
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

PS: The project was created on windows 10 (working fine) and i'm trying to continue on Mac Os.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Don't even know where the error comes from. It will be therefore difficult to me to know exactly what to share.

Comment: You can start with `listeners`. Search for it and try to locate where you try to access `listeners` property of something.